# Facebook is cropping my shared URL on Android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to share an URL via Intent on Android with:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain");
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.share_subject));
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            "http://example.com/mypage");
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Weiterempfehlen"));
```

Works fine on all apps except for Facebook, which is cropping my URL to http://example.com.

I've looked for other Intent.EXTRA_XY flags but none seemed appropiate.

Any way around this?

Comment: Try Add a trailing slash
"http://example.com/mypage/"